# Show progress status of each dowloaded files

Tags: php, node.js, ajax, sockets

I'm developing an application where I have to download some large files (approx 200MB -250MB) and show it's real time download progress status on web even if window is closed and reopened.It should also update the file status if downloading became fail of individual file

Something like this

```
name    action    progress    status
------------------------------------
file1   download  20%         in-progress
file2   download  60%         in-progress
file3   download  10%         in-progress
file4   download  45%         in-progress
file5   download  25%         in-progress
file6   download  100%        completed
file6   download  0%          failed
```

How can I achieved this in my application, right now the application uses `PHP` and `MYSQL`. I'm confused weather should I use AJAX or node and socket programming.

I need the best suggestion so that my application run smoothly and uses friendly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js client-side progress indicator for server operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033617/node-js-client-side-progress-indicator-for-server-operations)